# struck in the logic

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a shell script to see if the ADM Process is down we need to get an alert via email,I have done that below the script,it is working fine if we have installed one ADM server on one machine,But my requirement is i have installed 3 ADM servers on one machine not sure how i can write the shell script to achieve this requirement.

script:-

```
export ADM =`ps -ef  | grep Adm | grep -v grep | wc -l`

if [ $ADM == 0 ];
then
echo "AdmServer is down on Dev $hostname" | mail -s xxxx.gmail.com
fi
```

Please help me out,

Thanks,

Comment: Variable assignments can't have spaces around `=`.

Comment: Why are you using `export`? Are there child processes that use the `ADM` variable?

Comment: If I understand question correctly changing `if [ $ADM == 0 ];` to `if [ $ADM != 3 ];` will work

Comment: No sir,Let me explain my question,I have 3 process running on my machine like p1,p2,p3, i need to write a shell script that i will getting an alert via email when any of the process is down.Please let me know if my question still confuses you

Comment: @KrupalPatel I posted the same thing as an anwer. I don't understand why it's not correct.

Comment: @KrupalPatel if your processes have different names, you should wrap that code in a loop. Or you can put OR conditions on grep like `grep -e 'p1|p2|p3'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether `$ADM` is `0`, check whether it's not `3`.

```
ADM=`ps -ef  | grep -c '[A]dm`

if [ $ADM -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "AdmServer is down on Dev $hostname" | mail -s xxxx.gmail.com
fi
```

The `-c` option to `grep` returns the count of matches, so you don't need to use `wc -l`. And putting one of the characters in brackets is a trick for parsing `ps` output so you don't need `grep -v grep` (because now the argument to `grep` is no longer the same as the process name you're searching for). And you should use `-eq` and `-ne` for comparing numbers; `==` and `!=` are for comparing strings.

There's no need to use `export` when assigning a variable that will just be used in that shell script. `export` is for creating environment variables, which are inherited by child processes.

Comment: Sorry Sir it is my mistake,I overlooked that

Comment: The reason am doing this is 
export ADM =`ps -ef  | grep Adm | grep -v grep | wc -l`
It will give the count with that count  am implementing the logic

Comment: I understand why you're assigning the variable. My question is why you're **exporting** it. You know the difference between shell variables and environment variables, don't you?